# Read and parse PGP keys

Tags: rsa, pgp

Good morning, my goal is to parse pgp keys but I am facing two problems.

- I don't know how pgp keys are encoded (for starters I deal with pgp keys generated by Rsa only)
- and nor do I know how to read the value of its main parameters

To be more precise, with a RSA key, the instruction:

```
 openssl rsa -in name -text -noout
```

gives me the value of n,e,d,p,q,dp,dq ... and it also helps me to know how RSA keys are encoded.
I would like to do something similar with my pup key but I do not know how.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Parsing PGP keys for what purpose ? Maybe have a look at [pgpdump](https://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/pgpdump/en/) for practice.

Comment: I just have to identify PGP keys with their main parameters among a set files.

Comment: I am not sure that pgpdump gives the parameters I am looking for. 

I am wondering if maybe, once we know that our pgp key has been generated by a RSA algorithm (for my example) we can use a parser for RSA keys.?

Comment: There is a python module that can parse PGP keys. Depends on what kind of attributes you're exactly looking for ?

Comment: Thanks ! What is the python module ?

Comment: I am looking for the numbers used in the RSA algorithm (n,e,d,p,q,dp,dq)

Comment: PGP does not store the d-mod-p-1 and d-mod-q-1 values for an RSA 'secret' (really, private) key, which are trivial to regenerate, and it stores p-inv-mod-q instead of q-inv-mod-p, which changes the computation but doesn't alter security.  See RFC4880 especially 5.5.3. Also IME `gpg --list-packets` does as well as `pgpdump`.